# Estimating number of customers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to analyze a simple model for businesses.  I'm not sure if the problem I'm having is with notation.  There seems to be some discrete structure I don't understand how to write down or otherwise use.

Suppose that $N_i$ new customers subscribe in the $i$th period, and that the $j$th customer to join in the $i$th period will stay subscribed for $L_{i,j}$ periods.  How do I express the total number of customers subscribed at the $i$ period $T_i$, in terms of the $N_i$ and $L_{i,j}$'s?

This almost isn't even a problem in probability (except for the modeling aspect) -- I just don't know how to count the numbers, even if the variables aren't random.

Edit:  I did some chugging, and have made some minor progress.

In particular, we have:

$$
\begin{align*}
T_0 &= 0 \\
T_1 &= N_1 - |\{j\mid L_{1,j} = 0\}| \\
T_2 &= T_1 + N_2 - |\{j\mid L_{1,j} = 1\}| - |\{j\mid L_{2,j} = 0\}|\\
T_2 &= N_1 + N_2 - |\{j\mid L_{1,j} = 0\}| - |\{j\mid L_{1,j} = 1\}| - |\{j\mid L_{2,j} = 0\}|
\end{align*}
$$

I hypothesize that $T_i$ satisfies:

$$
T_i = \sum_{k=1}^{k=i} N_i - \sum_{k=1}^{k=i} \sum_{l=1}^{l = k} |\{j\mid L_{l,j} = k - l\}|
$$

Can this be taken further?  My thinking is that we can reindex the double sum, to sum over "columns" instead of "rows" first (but it's late and I'm not sure what it gets us).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to look in the reverse. There are $N_i$ new customers at the end of period $i$; there are $\# \{j\ |\  L_{i-1,j}>1 \}$ subscribed from the previous period,  etc, so you want the sum
$\sum_{k=0}^n \#\{j\ |\ L_{n-k,j}>k\}$.